# Modifying XDocument Query with Variables

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, linq, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to construct an XDocument query based upon the selections of checkboxes.

I have the following code, which isn't working, because I'm not sure of the syntax required. I think it's fairly obvious what it's trying to achieve; it's almost how I've constructed Where statements before in SQL. There will be around 16 checkboxes in the final code, which is the reason for using multiple If statements.

```
    Private Sub NextWord_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles NextWord.Click

    Dim WordDictionary As XDocument = XDocument.Load("Dictionary Resources\Dictionary.xml")

    Dim CheckSelection As String

    If NounCheckbox.Checked = True Then
        CheckSelection = CheckSelection & "noun"
    End If

    If AdjectiveCheckbox.Checked = True Then
        CheckSelection = CheckSelection & "adjective"
    End If


    Dim ToList = From x In WordDictionary.Root.Elements("Word") Where x.Elements("Type").Value = CheckSelection

    For Each result In ToList
        Console.WriteLine(result)
    Next

End Sub
```

For completeness, the XML file has this structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root>
  <Word ID="1">
    <Type>adjective</Type>
    <English></English>
    <Thai></Thai>
    <Meaning></Meaning>
    <Audio>Dictionary Resources\Sound Files\1.wav</Audio>
    <Picture></Picture>
    <Transliteration></Transliteration>
  </Word>
...
...
</Root>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to query the XML based on multiple checked selections you should add the selections to a `HashSet` (a `List` works too, but a `HashSet` is a better choice in this case).

```
Dim selectedTypes As New HashSet(Of String)

If NounCheckbox.Checked Then
    selectedTypes.Add("noun")
End If

If AdjectiveCheckbox.Checked Then
    selectedTypes.Add("adjective")
End If

Dim query = From x in WordDictionary.Root.Elements("Word")
            Where selectedTypes.Contains(x.Element("Type").Value)
            Select x
```

UPDATE: to access the results by index directly you could use `query.ElementAt(1)` but this isn't the best option in terms of performance if you plan to access different items by index. You should use a list instead. You can do that by setting up a new variable using `Dim results = query.ToList()` or alter the query as follows:

```
Dim results = (From x in WordDictionary.Root.Elements("Word")
              Where selectedTypes.Contains(x.Element("Type").Value)
              Select x).ToList()
```

Now that you have a list, you can access an item by its index. Indices are zero-based, so to access the second item in a list, you should use `results(1)`.

```
Label1.Text = results(1).Element("English").Value
```

Comment: If query returns 3 nodes, and I wanted to refer to the second, what syntax would I use to do this please? Obviously select in my syntax is wrong `Label1.Text = query.Select(2).Element("English").Value`

Comment: Thanks Ahmad, that's great. As you can tell I'm very new to XML. What is the reasoning behind checking if selectedTypes.Contains the x.Element("Type").Value rather than checking if the x.Element("Type").Value contains the selectedTypes? Writing it as the latter seems to make more sense to me; is it just down to the data types the Contains argument will accept?

Comment: @Andy the idea is you have multiple types, which are added to `selectedTypes`. Think of it as a bag full of various items we're interested in. We use it to filter against anything we get. It must exist in our "bag" to be accepted. When we inspect `x.Element("Type").Value` it returns *one* type. We check that type against the `selectedTypes` "bag" of possibilities. If it exists, it returns `true`, otherwise `false`. You can't reverse the check... there's no concept of `"string".ExistsIn(selectedTypes)`. So yes, by using the `HashSet` or `List` types, we use the `Contains` method to check.